# Android Camera Resolution with Intent

Tags: java, android, camera

I would like to set the resolution of the photo taken in android as the resolution is too high on some phones. This is my current code:

```
                // start take photo activity
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

I have read about setting the camera parameters to the required size but where do I put this as I am just calling the intent? I don't need anything special with the camera apart from specifying the res.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there's no safe way to tell the Intent the resolution - since there are a lot of different camera apps from almost every manufacturer out there. Some may have parameters that you can pass. But i think the safest way is to take the photo and then scale it down by yourself. By calling something like

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```